# Banach-Steinhaus theorem for nets?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider an uncountable set $I$ and let $A=\mbox{Fin}(I)$ be the family of finite subsets of $I$ ordered by inclusion. Let $E$ be a normed space and $F$ be a Banach space. Suppose moreover we have a net $(T_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ of bounded operators between $E$ and $F$. I want to show that $(T_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ is convergent to a certain operator $T$. Is there any version of Banach-Steinhaus theorem valid in this case? That is, what I can show is the fact that $(T_\alpha x)_{\alpha\in A}$ is convergent in $Y$ to $(Tx)_{\alpha\in A}$ for each $x\in X$. Can I conclude that $(T_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}\to T$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude this at all, even when you have a sequence.  See the corollary and the note [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle#Uniform_boundedness_principle).

The pointwise limit *defines* a bounded operator, but the sequence of operators does not necessarily converge (in the norm topology) to the operator defined by the pointwise limit.

Comment: Banach-Steinhaus requires $\{T_\alpha x:\alpha\in A\}$ to be bounded for each $x$, and convergent nets need not be bounded in general, so there potentially is a difference.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Nice catch.  I don't immediately see how to fix this potential problem, so I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I have $\sup_{\alpha \in A, \|x\|\leq 1}\|T_\alpha x\|<\infty$. So, is $T$ a limit in this case?